Prove $\int_{0}^{\infty} x\sin(x^n)dx$ is convergent and $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \int_{0}^{\infty} x\sin(x^n)dx = 0 $ for $n >2$
As for now I substitued:
$ y = x^n $
$ \frac{dy}{n} = x^{n-1}dx $
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x\sin(x^n)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{x})^{n-2}x^{n-1}\sin(x^{n})dx=\frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{y^{\frac{n-2}{n}}})\sin(y) dy}{n}$$
So the only thing that remains, is to show that the integral is convergent.
I've been thinking about splitting the integral into two:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{y^{\frac{n-2}{n}}})\sin(y) dy=\int_{0}^{1} (\frac{1}{y^{\frac{n-2}{n}}})\sin(y) dy+ \int_{1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{y^{\frac{n-2}{n}}})\sin(y) dy $$
If we do it like that we can tell how sin(y) behaves in the neighbourhood of $0$.
$\lim_{{x \to 0}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$
$\int_{0}^{1} (\frac{1}{y^{\frac{n-2}{n}}})\sin(y) dy$ ~ $\int_{0}^{1} (\frac{1}{y^{\frac{2}{n}}}) dy$
$\frac{2}{n} < 1 $ for $ n > 2 $
hence this part of the splitted integral is actually convergent but I'm not entirely sure what to do about the other one.

The integral converges for $n > 2$, and there is an explicit formula for its value, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2606464/42969. Can we close this as a duplicate?

@MartinR: It seems that the OP was asking about the sequence $I_n$ being convergent as $n\rightarrow\infty$ and that the limit is $0$ ($I_n$ being the improper integrals in the posting).

@Mittens: Yes, and unless I am mistaken, that follows immediately from the formula in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2609672/42969 .

@MartinR: sure, if the OP is versed in the basic tricks of the Gamma function (Euler's reflection formula for example). I just wanted to OP to know about that.

@Mittens: $I_n \to 0$ probably already follows from $I_n = \frac 1n \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1-2/n}}, dx$, right at the begining of that answer.
